# JQuery (!= ) for XPATH is not working correctly

Tags: jquery, html

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("[href!='http://www.google.net']").hide();
  });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h2>This is a heading</h2>
<p class="waqar">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p class="wr">This is another paragraph.</p>
<a href="http://www.google.net">google</a>
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com">yahoo</a>
<button>Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

When i run this code whole page goes blank. Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$("[href!='http://www.google.net']")` selects all items (tags), which "href" property is not equal to "http://www.google.net". For example, `<body>` tag have no property "href" => its value is not equal to "http://www.google.net" => it should be hidden.

Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("a[href!='http://www.google.net']").toggle();
  });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h2>This is a heading</h2>
<p class="waqar">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p class="wr">This is another paragraph.</p>
<a href="http://www.google.net">google</a>
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com">yahoo</a>
<button>Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How would i select all tags with attribute href or any other specified attribute?

Comment: +1 As an additional point, if you want to select all elements with an `href` attribute that isn't Google, you can use the [has attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) as well: `$('[href][href!="http://www.google.net"]')`.

Comment: Currently, you ARE selecting all tags (including `<body>`, `<head>`, perhaps even `<html>`). If you wanna select all tags inside some tag (for example, all tags inside `<body>`) use "parent > child" selector. E.g.: $("body > [href != 'http://google.com'")